# How does $49\cdot\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{x}-\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^x$ become $\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{x}\left(49-1\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Rewrite $\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{x-2}-\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^x$ as $A\cdot\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^x$ is a question I got.

Now the answer to A is 48, but I don't really get how they got to the answer:

$$\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{x-2}-\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^x = \frac{\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{x}}{\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{2}}-\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^x$$

$$ = 49\cdot\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{x}-\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^x$$
so far this makes sense, multiplying by the reciprocal of $\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^2}$ ends up in $\left(\frac{7}{1}\right)^2$ I suppose, so 49. But the next step does not make any sense to me:
$$ = \left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{x}\left(49-1\right)$$

How do we end up with 49 minus 1? Or do I have to treat this expression the same as $10x - x$ which is the same as $10x - 1x$, so we end up with $9x$. And in this specific case the $x$'s are the fractions to the $x$ power?

Comment: What is the problem? 49x-x=48x

Comment: $$\text{this}\cdot\text{that}-\text{other}\cdot\text{that}=(\text{this}-\text{other})\cdot\text{that}$$ is true *regardless* of the specific nature of "$\text{this}$", "$\text{that}$", and "$\text{other}$".

Comment: $\color{blue}a*B + \color{blue}a*C = \color{blue}a(B+C)$.  That is the law of distribution.  $49(\frac 17)^x - (\frac 17^x) = 49\cdot \color{blue}{(\frac 17)^x} - 1\cdot \cdot \color{blue}{(\frac 17)^x}= \cdot \color{blue}{(\frac 17)^x}(49 - 1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, for all $a$ and $b$, due to the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property), you have

$$(a-1)b = ab - b \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, with $a = 49$ and $b = \left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^x$, you get what you're asking about, i.e.,

$$49\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^x - \left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^x = (49 - 1)\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^x \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: Aha, so they indeed undid the distributive property of the fraction :) Great explanation, thanks!